# Is there anyy way to transcode MPEG-PS with incorrect timecodes to MPEG-4 AVC with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I have a few video files in `MPEG-PS\MPEG-4 Visual\MPEG Audio` format, those files have corrupted time codes which results in inability of most players to play it correctly. When I'm trying to open it with VLC, it plays the video fine but total file duration indicator is changing constantly, jumping back and forth.

I tried simply converting the files to `MPEG-4\AVC\AAC` with this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -y -loglevel info  -i "D:\input.mp4"  -f mp4  "D:\output.mp4"
```

But it have resulted in a file with incorrect duration. Video stream playback is fine but general duration of the resulted file is a few hours longer than it should be, meaning there are a few hours of black frames and silence in the end.

Is there any way to convert `MPEG-PS\MPEG-4 Visual\MPEG Audio` to `MPEG-4\AVC\AAC` with correcting or creating a new timeline?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg.exe -nostdin -y  -i "D:\input.mp4"  -fflags +genpts -f mp4  "D:\output.mp4"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- use the -t parameter to stop at the desired end point
- Use a `concat` input: A very short correct clip (e.g. 1 Frame black) and then the defective clip. With a `concat` input, ffmpeg will use the timestamps from the first input, then adapt the following timestamps to seamlessly append to it.

You might also want to use the `-c copy` parameter to avoid reencoding if not necessary.

Comment: Is there any way to tell ffmpeg to stop at the end of the audio stream since it seems to be of a correct length. Manually entering -t for every file works but a bit tedious.

Comment: There is: something along the lines of `-i file.mp4 -i file.mp4 -map [0:a] -map [1:v] -c copy -shortest`